# Dificuldades para escrever uma url amigável (global) no web config

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, url, web.config

Fiz essa mesma pergunta na versão em inglês mas não tive sucesso!

Eu tenho uma aplicação que vai ser traduzida para três idiomas pt/en/es. Até aí tranquilo vou utilizar GlobalResources, não tenho problemas com isso, mas estou tendo muitas dificuldades ao tentar escrever uma url com a seguinte aparência:

```
Eu tenho isso     => http://www.teste.com.br/algumacoisa
Mas preciso disso => http://www.teste.com.br/pt/algumacoisa
```

Eu sei que parece simples, mas não consegui trabalhar com essa url. Até posso colocar tudo o que eu tentei aqui, mas não sei se vai adiantar, se precisarem mandem nos comentários que altero a questão.

ps: as urls estão no web.config da app. E estou no Web Forms

**UPDATE 1**

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- Produtos -->
    <rule name="produtos">
      <match url="^produtos/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/produtos/Detail.aspx?id={R:1}" appendQueryString="false"/>
    </rule>
    <!-- /Produtos -->
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Em ASP.NET a determinação da linguagem não é feita, em geral, na URL e sim no web.config ou ela é detectada automaticamente pelo navegador. Por exemplo, seu site teria sempre a URL http://www.teste.com.br/algumacoisa independente da linguagem. Se a mesma fosse pt ou en, a URL permaneceria a mesma. O que seria diferente seria a configuração no web.config. Para alcançar isso, você utiliza o mecanismo de internacionalização do .NET. Caso você, mesmo assim, deseje gerar URLs com a linguagem, daí você terá que utilizar URL rewrite: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net

Comment: É a ideia seria recuperar esse pt/en e tal, por meio de query string assim como faço nas outras url's, que postei por exemplo ali...

Comment: Por que não utilizar o mecanismo de internacionalização do ASP.NET?

Comment: @EduardoFernandes você está dizendo sobre o GlobalResources ?

Comment: Você também pode utilizar local resources. Veja o seguinte link com uma explicação bem interessante: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334820/Using-Globalization-and-Localization-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é a implementação de um *HTTP Module* que irá interceptar todos os requests, e decidir qual página será executada. Segue um exemplo de acordo com sua necessidade:

```
public class LocaleParser : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var req = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        var targetUrl = req;

        if (req.IndexOf('/') != -1)
        {
            var langparm = req.Split('/')[1].ToLower();

            switch (langparm)
            {
                case "pt":
                    HttpContext.Current.Items["locale"] = "PT";
                    targetUrl = req.Substring(3);
                    break;
                case "en":
                    HttpContext.Current.Items["locale"] = "EN";
                    targetUrl = req.Substring(3);
                    break;
                case "es":
                    HttpContext.Current.Items["locale"] = "ES";
                    targetUrl = req.Substring(3);
                    break;
            }
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer(targetUrl);
    }

    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

Mais informações (em Inglês): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227673(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Cara fiz um teste estaticamente aqui, funcionou perfeitamente! Muuuito obrigado! +1 e resposta correta, pena que não tem mais premiação! uaheuahuea :D Valeuu mesmo!

Comment: @BrunoCasali Que bom que funcionou pra você! No caso de qualquer dúvida,sinta-se à vontade para perguntar.